# Python / Jupyter Notebook: Parsing one text file with multiple sets of data into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, import

I am a fairly new Python user and have been using pandas and matplotlib to do some data analysis for my research. In particular, I have a data file with 3 sets of data inside: 2 column vectors and an array (see link here to google drive for a simple 3x3 sample of the same format:[Sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F4uHJe3pLRVgPekLRFQBxDsfhjjxrs3U/view?usp=sharing). In the end, I need to plot this as a 2D heatmap with the column vectors specifying x and y axis and the array filling my heat points.

I could use pandas.read_csv() with skiprows to do this for one file, but the dimension of each vector and array varies across all of the simulations I have run. Thus, I would have to find the start and end of each set of data for each different file. The biggest files I have are (229, 1), (229, 1), (229, 229).

My question is this: is there a way to specify a start and end to each set of data based on the formatting approach that my output files have? This could be done either into pandas dataframe or into arrays. I prefer dataframes only for the ease of performing computations before plotting.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, I think it's all about data preprocessing or cleaning.

Here's some tips:

- your 3 datasets in 1 file are split by '\n\n' (two continual \n), you can `open()` it, then `.read()` all content, then `.split('\n\n')` it first.
- for each split dataset, the first row is not important(or just has some name or (row,column) info), if they have some sort rule, you could simply skip it (maybe `.split('\n')[1:]`).
- for each split dataset, other rows is the data content, you can pass it to `pd._read_csv` or something like that.

Hope these tips can help you.